# Real non algebraic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I know that there are countably infinite many algebraic numbers and uncountably infinite many real numbers. Therefore there exist real numbers that are not algebraic numbers. Are there any simple proofs that show certain real numbers are not algebraic?

Comment: i suggest you look into [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number). (The proofs for specific transcendental numbers that occur in nature like $e$ and $\pi$ are harder and came later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real non-algebraic numbers are called transcendental numbers. It's usually a lot harder to proof that a number is  transcendental than proving that a number is algebraic. [Here is an example](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2302515?origin=crossref&seq=1) for the number $\pi$.